# How to restrict a JFileChooser to a custom file type?

Tags: java, swing, filechooser

I am having slight trouble with `JFileChooser`. I want to restrict to only read certain kind of files. Another stack answer recommended using a `FileNameExtensionFilter`, but this doesn't seem to be working. This might be because I have to restrict it to a custom file type called a "battle" file. The filter is not recognizing this file type since it is not a commonly used file type. the assignment I am doing requires this and therefore I have to use this type of file. On reaching the directory, it doesn't allow me to choose the file.

Following is my code snippet:

```
public class battleship_window extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JLabel loglabel;
JButton selectbutton;
JButton startbutton;
JLabel filename;
File file;
//JLabel scorearray[]=new JLabel[10];
char alphabet[]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'};
battleship_window()
{
    super("Battleship");
    setSize(1050,550);
    setLocation(50,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel logpanel=new JPanel();
    makelogpanel(logpanel);
    this.add(logpanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.setVisible(true);

}
public void makelogpanel(JPanel logpanel)
{
    loglabel=new JLabel("Log: You are now in edit mode, click to place your ships");
    selectbutton=new JButton("Select File");
    startbutton=new JButton("Start");
    startbutton.setEnabled(false);
    filename=new JLabel("File:");
    logpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(logpanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    logpanel.add(loglabel);
    logpanel.add(selectbutton);
    logpanel.add(filename);
    logpanel.add(startbutton);
    selectbutton.addActionListener(this);

}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    battleship_window bw=new battleship_window();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==selectbutton)
    {
        JFileChooser fileDialog=new JFileChooser();
        fileDialog.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Battle file", "battle");
        fileDialog.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
               file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();
               filename.setText("File:" + file.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

}

How can I achieve this either through the above method or any other method?
Please note that the code compiles and i delted some of my code above to make it more readable so there might be some syntax errors in the above code.

Comment: `battle` been the extension of the file?  Like `Big.battle`?

Comment: Yes battle is the extension, so for example i am trying to sue myfile.battle

Comment: Works fine for me. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Let me edit the question with the entire code. The problem is that the JFileChooser opens but when i go to a directory with a battle file, it has not set it to selectable.

Comment: You code snippet works just fine for me...all be it the layout sucks...

Comment: Refer http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/A_351-Custom-File-Filtering-Using-Java-File-Choosers.html

Comment: ...Still don't know what wasn't working...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have a program I am writing at the moment that has multiple JFileChooser's, each of them requiring to look for only specific file types. This example would allow you to have the same idea, so that if in the future, you need to allow for different file types, you are ready to go. I have created a custom class that extends upon FileFilter

```
public class CustomExtension extends FileFilter
{
    private String type;

    public CustomExtension(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    } 

    public Boolean accept(File file)
    {  
        if(file.isDirectory())
            return true;

        String ext = getExtension(file);
        if(ext == null)
            return false;

        switch(type)
        {
            case "battle":
                if(ext.equals("battle"))
                    return true;
                else 
                    break;
            default:
                System.out.println(type + " has not been set up in the switch statement yet");
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case "battle":
                return "Only battle file supported";
        }
    }

    public String getExtension(File f)
    {
        String ext = null;
        String filename = f.getName();

        int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');

        if(i > 0 && i < filename.length() - 1)
            ext = s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();

        return ext;
    }
}
```

I have been using this for a while now and I haven't noticed any bugs. To set up a JFileChooser so that it uses this filter, you would use:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileFilter(new CustomExtension("battle"));
```

Now your JFileChooser will only display directories, and files that end in .battle

Comment: So, what benefit does this have over `FileNameExtensionFilter` which does the same job?

Comment: I remember when I was looking up how to restrict the file types, I was referring to the [Java File Choosers tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) (included the link for your benefit siddhant, in case you hadn't seen it, it's quite useful). I believe I may have needed some custom functionality, or a little more control over some of the output messages, but honestly the exact reason I have forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be commonly used file type to regednize with file chooser.
 Just create a file and rename it with extention to:

"**My File.battle**"
Then browse with your program. It will show the file.

**Or try this code:**

```
JFileChooser fileDialog = new JFileChooser();
fileDialog.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {            
    File file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();

    if(file.getName().endsWith(".battle")){
        System.out.println("Selected file is battle file");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalied file type");
    }   
}
```

Comment: `JFileChooser` is perfectly capable of and is designed to provide post validation of the input before the dialog returns, that's the point of a file dialog...you've just removed this user feature and provided a level of annoyance to the user...

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I know that. His code also working. I just showed another way to filter the file.

Comment: But it's probably one of the worst ways.  The `JFileChooser` has two mechanisms for providing filtering capabilities.  You solution will probably need to add a `do-while` loop to keep prompting the user for another `File` until the work out what is accepted.  Sure, you've shown them a "different" way, but it decreases the usability of the program and annoys the users, especially when there are better ways to achieve the desired result. I'm still waiting for the OP to actually present a runnable example which demonstrates there problem, as all the code they've provided works fine as is

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
fileDialog.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("", "battle"));
```

instead of

```
fileDialog.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
```

The `addChoosableFileFilter` will get added in the JFileChooser's combo box named `Files of Type`.

Comment: All that does is makes the display of the filter in the dialog blank...

Comment: Can I understand why this answer is downvoted?

Comment: Not the down-voter, but, it doesn't do anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you explain why it doesn't do anything? The accepted answer has also recommended the same thing at the bottom of his answer. The `setFileFilter` and `addChoosableFileFilter` are two different things. The `addChoosableFileFilter` just adds that filter to the combo box for choosing the desired filters, whereas the `setFileFilter` will just display the directories and files which ends with `.battle`

Comment: Because there is no identifiable problem.  Every piece of code the OP has posted works, applying `FileNameExtensionFilter` to `setFileFilter` is pointless as it does the same job as `addChoosableFileFilter`, it just adds more control to the user...None of the answers actually answer a question, because the OP can't produce an example which demonstrates there problems, so we're dancing around coming up with pointless hacks for no reason which doesn't help the OP or anyone else who might be looking for answers to what might be a simular problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer Do you believe the OP just wasn't sure of what they were actually wanting? I was reading the comments up the top, it seems like they weren't aware there code was fine to begin with, even with you mentioning it...

Comment: @Stevo I have absolutely no idea. They presented a snippet, which work fine, then they presented a runnable example, which worked fine. I simply can't replicate the issue that the OP claims to be having...